# Changing contact list & reordering the list of apps on a Motorola 360 watch

Tags: contacts, motorola, android-wear

So I've just bought a Motorola 360 Android watch, and I'm having trouble with figuring out if I can reorder the list of contacts that I am presented with when swiping to the right twice (going past the list of apps and into the list of contacts). It seems to only have the possibility of displaying the list in the order of I've contacted people. Can that really be the only way to see the list?

Also, the list of apps that the watch presents has multiple instances that I don't really use all that much and would rather reorder further down the list (so I can access those I do use more often faster). I haven't been able to find any information about this anywhere. Is this list static?

I'm an Android developer my self, and must say that the capabilities for customization in these wearable devices are surprisingly shallow and lacking in high impact obvious ways.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about contacts, but if you are running the latest Android Wear (Android Wear 1.1.1929530/Android OS 5.1.1) the first three apps in your list should be the most recent ones. I'm not aware of any system level customization beyond creating your own watch face or watch app.